# Anyone have any idea how TabStop works in iText 5.5.0

Tags: itext

I'm still trying to learn iText and have a few of the concepts down.  However I can't figure out what TabStop is or how to use it.  My particular problem is that I want to fill the end of all paragraphs with a bunch of dashes.  I believe this is called a TabStop and I see the class in the itext jar but I have no clue on how to use it.  I must be searching the wrong thing on google, but I've come up with nothing.  The iText in Action book also doesnt seem to even know of the existance of this class so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [`ChunkTest`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/text/ChunkTest.java) class in iText's test suite. It contains several use cases of the tab stop functionality. For instance:

```
java.util.List<TabStop> tabStopsList = new ArrayList<TabStop>();
tabStopsList.add(new TabStop(100, new DottedLineSeparator()));
tabStopsList.add(new TabStop(200, new LineSeparator(), TabStop.Alignment.CENTER));
tabStopsList.add(new TabStop(300, new DottedLineSeparator(), TabStop.Alignment.RIGHT));
p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Hello world", f));
p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(tabStopsList, 50));
addTabs(p, f, 0, "la|la");
ct.addElement(p);
```

The `TabStop` functionality was introduced *after* the **iText in Action** books were written. They'll be documented in one of the new books.

For another example, see http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/tabbing-examples