# How do you add line for sign in ITEXT PDF java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need add a  line for sign in my document pdf with Itex java. But i don't meet like do it.

I need the following:

### (The text of my document).......................

---

name people.
here: a line for that the people can signing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say a line for sign, you confuse people because you are probably not talking about a digital signature. If you were, you'd not ask for a line, but for a rectangle that defines the signature field. For more info about digital signatures, read the free ebook [Digital SIgnatures for PDF documents](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html).

One could rephrase your question to "how do I add a line where people can place a wet signature?" But that would be a bad quesion too: your question isn't about signatures at all. Your question is about adding a dotted line.

That's a question that has been answered in another free ebook: [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so/). In this book, you'll find these questions:

- [How to underline text with a dotted line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382717)
- [itextsharp how to add a full line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233630/itextsharp-how-to-add-a-full-line-break)
- [Anyone have any idea how TabStop works in iText 5.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650016/anyone-have-any-idea-how-tabstop-works-in-itext-5-5-0)
- [How to create a custom dashed line separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752409/)
- [Create Index File(TOC) for merged pdf using itext library in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548552/create-index-filetoc-for-merged-pdf-using-itext-library-in-java)

Although these examples may not be "on topic" at first sight, they all have the `DottedLineSeparator` in common in their answer.

Either you want something like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("                            ");
DottedLineSeparator dottedline = new DottedLineSeparator();
dottedline.setOffset(-2);
dottedline.setGap(2f);
p.add(dottedline);
document.add(p);
```

This creates a `Paragraph` consisting of white space that is underlined with a dotted line.

Or you want something like this:

```
Chunk linebreak = new Chunk(new DottedLineSeparator());
doc.Add(linebreak);
```

This creates a full dotted line (and the answer from which I've taken this snippet explains how to tweak the length of the line).

Or you want something like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Please sign here: ");
p.add(new Chunk(new DottedLineSeparator()));
p.add("(wet ink signature)");
document.add(p);
```

Your question is too unclear to assess which of the above would be the best solution, but I'm sure you'll figure that out once you decide to read the documentation.